# How can I give an object a temporary mark in Sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I use Sequelize to load items from database. The item contain a number type attribute called `tValue`, if `tValue` is null, then I need to assign a value to it, if not null, then do nothing and then pass all items to a function and it will return a new array.

What I want is to revert those updated items, make them back to null tValue before I save this list of array to database.

The issues is I don't know which item originally contain null tValue, because all of them have value now.

Can I give an object a temporary mark, so I can revert those items with mark.

The code snippet I do to assign value is like this

```
const mustHaveTValueArray = await Promise.all(
        samples.map(async (s) => {
          if (!s.tValue) {
            console.warn(`sample ${s.id} do not have a t value`);
            await s.update({ tValue: randomValue });
            return s;
          } else {
            return s;
          }
        })
      );
```

mustHaveTValueArray will be passed to a function, and return a new array

`const newArray = reorderFunction(mustHaveTValueArray)`

Each element in `newArray` now have valid tValue, how can I detect those originally have null tValue

Answer (score 0):

the idea just come up in my head, guys

```
let temporaryIds = [];
const mustHaveTValueArray = await Promise.all(
        samples.map(async (s) => {
          if (!s.tValue) {
            console.warn(`sample ${s.id} do not have a t value`);
            await s.update({ tValue: randomValue });
            temporaryIds.push(s.id);
            return s;
          } else {
            return s;
          }
        })
      );
```

Then I can use this temporaryIds to find which one originally have null tValue, like this

```
const finalArray = await Promise.all(
        newArray.map(async (n) => {
          if (temporaryIds.includes(n.id)) {
            console.log('revert');
            await n.update({ tValue: null });
            return n;
          } else {
            return n;
          }
        })
      );
```

what do you think, is it this make sense to you, guys

22/10/22 update:

model.update actually is calling `set` and then calling `save`, so what I need to do, I should use `set` instead of `update`, otherwise it will write db which is not my purpose. `set`is perfectly fit my situation, instruction from official document:

> Set is used to update values on the instance (the sequelize
> representation of the instance that is, remember that nothing will be
> persisted before you actually call save). In its most basic form set
> will update a value stored in the underlying dataValues object.

so updated code would be

```
const mustHaveTValueArray =
        samples.map((s) => {
          if (!s.tValue) {
            console.warn(`sample ${s.id} do not have a t value`);
            s.set({ tValue: randomValue });
            return s;
          } else {
            return s;
          }
        });
```

And I can do whatever I want with `mustHaveTValueArray`

question solved